# Position of "tip" in an Arrow-Unicode character

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, fonts

Is there a way one can find the position of the "tip" of an arrow character in unicode?

For example I have  ↱ and wanna find the position of the ">", so that I can draw the character at the appropriate y-position in my widget.

Comment: Is it bad that uncontrollable laughter emitted after reading the first half of title? You will probably need some sort of OCR library for this as the usual GetTextExtent type API isn't going to be enough.

Comment: It might be easier to create an image of an arrow for which you *know* the position and use that.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the font.

You could try blitting the glyph using a library like FreeType (not sure if Qt has glyph blitters) to an image buffer and then find the right-most pixel which should be the tip.